# PDFCreator "User-defined type not defined" Error with PDF reference- Excel 2013 VBA

Tags: vba, reference, compiler-errors, pdf-generation

here is the code I am trying to use, the problem is that every time I try to run it `Dim pdfjob As PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator`gives me an error of type:

> User-defined type not defined

I have gone into tools and added the reference to PDFCreator, which maps to PDFcreator.tlb and yet it still isn't working...
I am at a loss here, not sure whats missing. I installed PDFCreator 2.1 on my PC and I am running windows 8.

```
Option Explicit
Sub PrintToPDF(ByVal sPDFName As String, ByVal sPDFPath As String)

    Dim pdfjob As PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator
    Dim sPDFName As String
    Dim sPDFPath As String
    Dim bRestart As Boolean

    '/// Change the output file name here! ///
    'sPDFName = "testPDF.pdf"
    'sPDFPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator

    'Check if worksheet is empty and exit if so
    If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.UsedRange) Then Exit Sub

    'Activate error handling and turn off screen updates
    On Error GoTo EarlyExit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set pdfjob = New PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator

    'Check if PDFCreator is already running and attempt to kill the process if so
    Do
        bRestart = False
        Set pdfjob = New PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator
        If pdfjob.cStart("/NoProcessingAtStartup") = False Then
            'PDF Creator is already running.  Kill the existing process
            Shell "taskkill /f /im PDFCreator.exe", vbHide
            DoEvents
            Set pdfjob = Nothing
            bRestart = True
        End If
    Loop Until bRestart = False

    'Assign settings for PDF job
    With pdfjob
        .cOption("UseAutosave") = 1
        .cOption("UseAutosaveDirectory") = 1
        .cOption("AutosaveDirectory") = sPDFPath
        .cOption("AutosaveFilename") = sPDFName
        .cOption("AutosaveFormat") = 0    ' 0 = PDF
        .cClearCache
    End With

    'Delete the PDF if it already exists
    If Dir(sPDFPath & sPDFName) = sPDFName Then Kill (sPDFPath & sPDFName)

    'Print the document to PDF
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut copies:=1, ActivePrinter:="PDFCreator"

    'Wait until the print job has entered the print queue
    Do Until pdfjob.cCountOfPrintjobs = 1
        DoEvents
    Loop
    pdfjob.cPrinterStop = False

    'Wait until the file shows up before closing PDF Creator
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Dir(sPDFPath & sPDFName) = sPDFName

Cleanup:
    'Release objects and terminate PDFCreator
    Set pdfjob = Nothing
    Shell "taskkill /f /im PDFCreator.exe", vbHide
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

EarlyExit:
    'Inform user of error, and go to cleanup section
    MsgBox "There was an error encountered.  PDFCreator has" & vbCrLf & "has been terminated.  Please try again.", vbCritical, vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Resume Cleanup
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `CreateObject("PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator")` instead of `New PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator`

Comment: Use the object browser to check out the pdfcreator namespace - is `PDFcreator` the right namespace, is `clsPDFcreator` a valid type name? I searched their website, but couldn't find any decent documentation on their API.  All I found was [this](http://www.pdf-tools.com/public/downloads/manuals/plba.pdf) but it's not real helpful.

Comment: There is a .zip with sample files available from their site as well - the documentation I linked to indicates this shows how to use most of the features.  Have you registered the PDFcreatorAPI.dll yet?

Comment: Not I have not registered the PDFcreatorAPI.dll, how do I go about that?